# How to show new data on listview whenever data change, Notifydatasetchanged()

Tags: android, distance, notifydatasetchanged

I used NotifyDataSetchanged() in order to show new data on the listview whenever data change.
But when I put the following codes, there's nothing on the listview.
What's the problem? and what should I do to figure it out?
Please let me know.

Big thanks to you!!

```
       String names[] = { 
            "Tom",
            "Jane",
            "Mary",
            };

    Double lati[] = { 
            35.000001,
            26.000001,
            67.000001,
            };  

    Double longi[] = { 
            129.000001,
            159.000001,
            100.000001,
            };          


    originalValues = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();

    HashMap<String, Object> temp;

    if (x==0){
        originalValues.clear();
            }
    else{
        int oriname = names.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < oriname; i++) {
            temp = new HashMap<String, Object>();

            temp.put("name",    names[i]);
            temp.put("lati",    lati[i]);
            temp.put("longi",   longi[i]);

            temp.put("dis",     Math.round(Math.round(6371000.0 * Math.acos(Math.sin(Math.PI/180 * lati[i]) * Math.sin(Math.PI/180 * Double.valueOf(x))
    + Math.cos(Math.PI/180 * lati[i]) * Math.cos(Math.PI/180 * Double.valueOf(x)) * Math.cos(Math.PI/180 * (longi[i] - Double.valueOf(y))))) / 1000));


            originalValues.add(temp);

        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    adapter = new CustomAdapter(this,R.layout.tab01_consul_row, originalValues);
    insurListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I see from your code, I think instead of making an arraylist of hashmaps (which is generally too complicated idea itself), make a class in which you will store three values: name, latitude and longitude. Then make a listview with adapter of the list of this objects.
For example, your listview items class :

```
public class Item {

    private String name;
    private double lati;
    private double longi;

    public Item() {

    }

    public Item(String name, double lati, double longi) {
        this.name = name;
        this.lati = lati;
        this.longi = longi;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public double getLati() {
        return lati;
    }

    public void setLati(double lati) {
        this.lati = lati;
    }

    public double getLongi() {
        return longi;
    }

    public void setLongi(double longi) {
        this.longi = longi;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name + ", " + lati + ", " + longi;
    }
}
```

Then make adapter class:

```
public class ItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<Item> items;
    private Context context;

    public ItemAdapter(Context context) {
        super();
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public ItemAdapter(Context context, List<Item> items) {
        super();
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return items.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lv_row, parent, false);
        TextView model = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.modelTV);
        model.setText(items.get(position).toString());
        return convertView;
    }

    public void reloadItems(List<Item> items) {
        this.items = items;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

And then in your activity class create your listview with this adapter.
Whenever you want to change your listview data, call your adapter's reloadItems method:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ListView lv;
    private ItemAdapter adapter;
    private List<Item> items;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        items = new ArrayList<Item>();
        items.add(new Item("Tom", 35.000001, 129.000001));
        items.add(new Item("Jane", 26.000001, 159.000001));
        items.add(new Item("Mary", 67.000001, 100.000001));
        adapter = new ItemAdapter(getApplicationContext(), items);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // if list items changed reload items with newer
        // by calling adapter.reloadItems(items);
        // the best way to do it though, is to do it in separate thread,
        // for example in asynctask
        adapter.reloadItems(items);
    }
}
```

Now only thing left is to create layout of the MainActivity and for the listview row.
Example layout of MainActivity, main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Hello World, TestActivity"
    />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />    
</LinearLayout>
```

The last one, layout for listview row, lv_row.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
    android:padding="6dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/modelTV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:textSize="16sp"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

And the manifest file, provide package name containing MainActivity class:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="your package here"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
  <application android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity 
        android:name="MainActivity"
        android:label="Simple Listview">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Notice that for example ItemAdapter class is not necessary here. You could use default ArrayAdapter instead. But in short, providing your own adapter gives you more control, over the listview data. It is also more handsome, when dealing with listview containing your own model.

Comment: Thanks so much. Unfortunately nothing changed even if I modified all things to apply what you suggested. If I solve this problem, I will add the code.

Answer (score 0):

you call  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); before you even initialize your adapter... i think you will get an exception there unless you did it somewhere else which i dont think so.

Fix that first and try again ...and please provide us more code

Comment: I applied many several suggestions to figure it out, but still unsolved. It is getting worse. If I reorganized all data codes, I will upload. I really appreciate it.